# How do i remove &#x2002; &#x2014; &#x2013; special characters from my XML files

Tags: ruby, xml, regex, parsing

this is a sample of the xml file

```
<row tnote="0">
<entry namest="col2" nameend="col4" us="none" emph="bld"><blst>
<li><text>Single, head of household, or qualifying widow(er)&#x2014;$55,000</text></li>
<li><text>Married filing jointly&#x2014;$115,000</text></li>
</blst></entry>
<entry colname="col6" ldr="1" valign="middle">&#x2002;</entry>
<entry colname="col7" valign="middle"> 5.</entry>
</row>
```

the `&#x2014;` etc represent HTML 4.0 entities. i want to store each line's text as an element of an array, but not if the line is just `&#x2002;`

```
if e.text.strip =~ /^&#x20[0-9][0-9];$/ then
next
else
subLines << e.text
end
```

but it doesn't seem to be working...is my regEx incorrect?

Comment: What language is this code in? What does `strip` do?

Comment: No, character references do not represent entities. It’s the other way round: Entities are used to represent character references. `&mdash;` is an entity reference and the entity named *mdash* represents the value `&#8212;` (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#h-24.2.1). So the entity reference `&mdash;` references to the character reference `&#8212;` that references the Unicode character U+2014.

Comment: @Gumbo: `U+nnnn` notation uses hex numbers, not decimal: `U+2014`

Comment: @Alan Moore: Ah yes, of course it does.

Answer (score 2):

`&#x...;` isn't an entity reference, it's a character reference. To an XML parser, `&#x2014;` is absolutely identical to the raw character `—`, so when you look at the DOM produced by an XML parser through a property such as `element.text` you won't see anything with an ampersand in it, but a simple `—` character.

So in principle, you'd match it with a regex something like `/[—– ]/`. However, if you are using Ruby 1.8, you've got the problem that the language itself doesn't have support for Unicode, so the character group in `/[—– ]/` won't quite work properly: it'll try to remove every byte in the UTF-8 representation of `–`, `—` and  , which will likely mangle any other characters.

A simple string replace for each target character would work correctly, as that doesn't require special character handling. (Naturally if you included characters like `—` directly in the source code you'd also have to get the file encoding of that script right, so probably easier to use a string literal escape like `"\xe2\x80\x94"`.)

Answer (score 1):

Because your regex is of the form `/^...$/`, it will only match against the entire string.  You will only skip text that consists entirely of one HTML entity.